# How to retrieve script name from full absolute URL using PHP?

Tags: php, parsing, url

I'm able to retrieve the full URL like: http://www-click08-co-uk/wonga.php
and I need to retrieve the script name "wonga" from it.

The url will be changing depending on what page the user is on and I will always need the word or phrase after the / and not including the .php, in the example above I would like to create a variable with the value of this being wonga

This is the code I currently have, where "argos" is, is where the database is searched and responds with the information I need, this is where the vaiable would be used

```
<?php
//-----------------------------------------------------
// Include files and set Classes
//-----------------------------------------------------
require_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/includes/common.php";


$db = new dbConnection();
$directorydata = new directorydata();
$phoneDirectory = new phoneDirectory();

$conn = $db->pdoConnect();
// Load the directorydata row via the row ID - 543 is "best buy"
//$directorydata->get($db, 543);

// Load the directorydata row via the url alias field
$directorydata->get($db, "Argos");

// Phone number isn't formatted coming out the DB
$formattedPhoneNumber = $phoneDirectory->formatPhoneNumber($directorydata->Number1);

?>
```

Comment: please improve your question, do you need the "wonga" or the rest of the URL. Where is your code, what have you tried so far??

Comment: parse_url() http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: OK, nice edit, but there is still the question what you tried to do that?

Comment: I have tried to use the parse and explode and this didn't seem to work

Comment: then, show us what you tried. could be something minor.

Comment: Your best bet is to look into using a `.htaccess` file and `mod_rewrite` to handle things like this. If you're using an MVC framework, they'll handle stuff like this. Either way, Google is your friend :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you didn't provide any code, I provide you a way to solve this on your own:

```
$url = "http://www-click08-co-uk/wonga.php";

// SEARCH and replace
// FIRST_FUNCTION => google => php trailing name component of path
// SECOND_FUNCTION => google => php explode a string by string
// THIRD_FUNCTION => google => php pop first element of array

$urlParts = SECOND_FUNCTION( ".", FIRST_FUNCTION( $url ) );

echo THIRD_FUNCTION( $urlParts );
```

OUTPUT:

```
wonga
```

Answer (score 0):

An example use of [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) could be:

```
$url = 'http://www-click08-co-uk/wonga.php?page=74';

$route = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
$routeTokens = explode('/', $route);
$scriptName = array_pop($routeTokens);

echo $scriptName;
```

which in this case outputs `wonga.php`.

Just note that this is a very rare task that you would have to take care of yourself. So instead of `parse_url` you might look at the bigger picture here and start looking for some good MVC framework.